# Singluarity Issue when Computing ICCs for Unordered Pairs

Tags: multilevel-analysis, intraclass-correlation

I have 2 datasets of sibling pairs: one from divorced parents and one from married parents). Each pair has a unique "family" value. For this research question, it does not matter what order the siblings come in. I want to see how similar are sibling1's ratings to sibling2's ratings for the "divorced parents" groups compared to the "married parents" group, so I am computing ICCs for each group. There are 20 subscales, so I am computing 20 ICCs per group (there is no composite score for this survey). Per the researchers' request, the data has been age and sex corrected, so all of the values in the dataset are residuals (e.g., -2.25e-17,  3.73e-17,  8.45e-16, -3.91e-16)

The dataset looks like this:

|Family |  Sibling  | Outcome1 |  Outcome2  | etc. |
|-------|-----------|----------|------------|------|
| 1     |    1      | 2.5E-14  | 2.76E-14   |      |
| 1     |    2      | 5.48E-14 | -9.2E-15   |      |
| 2     |    1      | -1.2E-14 | 7.69E-13   |      |
| 2     |    2      | -3.3E-15 | 1.08E-14   |      |
etc.

I am currently using this code:
model <- lmer(outcome ~ 1 + (1|family),REML=FALSE,data=data)
icc(model)

This works for some outcome variables, but for others I get these errors:
boundary (singular) fit: see help('isSingular')
Warning message:
Can't compute random effect variances. Some variance components equal zero. Your model may suffer
from singularity (see `?lme4::isSingular` and `?performance::check_singularity`).
Solution: Respecify random structure! You may also decrease the `tolerance` level to enforce the
calculation of random effect variances.

How can I resolve an issue like this?

Finally, if I can figure out how to compute the remaining ICCs without getting errors, does it make sense to average the ICCs in each group to yield a composite ICC score?

Thank you kindly for any feedback and help.